# Get only unique items in a list and track the change by puting it in a dictionary - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have the following list.

`my_list = ['20/20',  '30/30',  '20/80',  '120/120',  '120/140',  '165/165', '30/170',  '165/175']`

I would like to remove any duplication and would like to keep unique items on the list and keep track of them by converting the dictionary.

For example, `20/20` should change to `20` and put in dictionary as `{'20/20':20}`, for `'30/30'` change to `30` and put it in dictionary as `{'30/30': 30}`, BUT for `'20/80'` it shouldn't be 20 because I have 20 in dictionary before so it should be `80` and put it in the dictionary as `{'20/80':80}`. The same procedure works for the rest of lists.

My expected result seems like the following dictionary.

`my_dict = {'20/20':20, '30/30': 30,  '20/80':80,  '120/120':120, '120/140':140,  '165/165': 165,  '30/170': 170,  '165/175':175}`

Is there any simple and intelligent way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension should be enough:

```
my_dict = dict((elem, elem.split('/')[1]) for elem in my_list)
```

Result:

```
{'20/20': '20', '30/30': '30', '20/80': '80', '120/120': '120', '120/140': '140', '165/165': '165', '30/170': '170', '165/175': '175'}
```

Comment: Additional question, is that possible to get the following result: Just identifying the removed item.  ```{'20/20': '20/-', '30/30': '30/-', '20/80': '-/80', '120/120': '120/-', '120/140': '-/140', '165/165': '165/-', '30/170': '-/170', '165/175': '-/175'}```